# Kubernetes autoscaling of GPU nodes

Tags: kubernetes, gpu, google-kubernetes-engine

I created a small cluster with GPU nodes on GKE like so:

```sh
# create cluster and CPU nodes
gcloud container clusters create clic-cluster \
    --zone us-west1-b \
    --machine-type n1-standard-1 \
    --enable-autoscaling \
    --min-nodes 1 \
    --max-nodes 3 \
    --num-nodes 2

# add GPU nodes
gcloud container node-pools create gpu-pool \
    --zone us-west1-b \
    --machine-type n1-standard-2 \
    --accelerator type=nvidia-tesla-k80,count=1 \
    --cluster clic-cluster \
    --enable-autoscaling \
    --min-nodes 1 \
    --max-nodes 2 \
    --num-nodes 1
```

When I submit a GPU job it successfully ends up running on the GPU node. However, when I submit a second job I get an `UnexpectedAdmissionError` from kubernetes:

> Update plugin resources failed due to requested number of devices
>   unavailable for nvidia.com/gpu. Requested: 1, Available: 0, which is
>   unexpected.

I would have expected the cluster to start the second GPU node and place the job there. Any idea why this didn't happen? My job spec looks roughly like this:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: <job_name>
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: decode
        image: "<decoder_image>"
        resources:
          limits:
            nvidia.com/gpu: 1
        command: [...]
     [...]     
     containers:
      - name: evaluate
        image: "<evaluation_image>"
        command: [...]
```

Comment: Have you tried to bring up the number of minimum and maximum nodes in your GPU node pool? I also noticed in your job that you are using 1 GPU limit in the job, have you tried not using limits? Seeing that your GPU node pool has the GPU’s on them, it may not be necessary to set that limit.

Comment: If I don't set the limit and rely on `nodeSelector` instead to pick the GPU node pool, the 2 jobs start but are assigned to the same node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource constraint needs to be added to the `containers` spec as well:

```
piVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: <job_name>
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: decode
        image: "<decoder_image>"
        resources:
          limits:
            nvidia.com/gpu: 1
        command: [...]
     [...]     
     containers:
      - name: evaluate
        image: "<evaluation_image>"
        resources:
          limits:
            nvidia.com/gpu: 1
        command: [...]
```

I only required a GPU in one of the `initContainers`, but this seems to confuse the scheduler. Now autoscaling and scheduling works as expected.

Comment: May I suggest using the NVIDIA device plugin? This will assist GKE with the GPU scheduling issues that you were experiencing. 
If you would like further information, you can visit the following [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-gpus/scheduling-gpus/#nvidia-gpu-device-plugin-used-by-gce).